# how to define slug in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship

i am using laravel 5.2
please tell me how to define slug on view
here is my view

```
@foreach($thread->forumindex()->where('slug', $slug)->firstorFail() as $forumindex)
<p>{{ $forumindex->title }}</p>
@endforeach
```

and here is my controller

```
public function forumcomment($thread_slug, $slug){

    $thread = thread::where('slug', $thread_slug)->firstorFail();

    return view('forum.index.show', compact('thread'));

}
```

Comment: what do you mean define 'slug' on view?. not really getting what your problem is.

Comment: i want to view only that post->title who related with post_id please show me some example i tried this but its won't work @SSuhat